# Twitter kit iOS - No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, twitterkit

After doing a pod update command to update all of the pods in my project I am getting the following error for the Twitter kit:

> /Users/user/iOS/Apps/myApp/Pods/TwitterKit/TwitterKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/TwitterKitResources.bundle: No such file or directory

I have looked in the TwitterKit folder and this the correct file path for the `Resources.bundle` :

> /Users/user/iOS/Apps/myApp/Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework

I have tried :

- Manually changing the directory of the resource.bundle by going on
  identity and type tab and clicking on the folder icon to set the file
  path.
- Removing the pod and then installing it.
- Cleaning and rebuilding the Xcode

However I am still getting the same error message. 
I have never had this issue before with pods, does anyone know how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the same error deleting the `TwitterKit.framework` from the `Frameworks` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it now